# data no inserting into mysql database due to difference in 'quotes'

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a very strange problem inserting values into my mysql database, using php, so i was running a test, the simplest of the simple insert; the following doesnt work:

```
<?php
include("config.php"); // put the *FULL* path to the file.

mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'lms'.'test2' ('trn') VALUES ('17')");

?>
```

However the following works:(Note the difference in single quotes)

```
<?php
include("config.php"); // put the *FULL* path to the file.

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `lms`.`test2` (`trn`) VALUES ('17')");

?>
```

I really can't see what the problem is could I get sum assistance please

Comment: in MySQL you cannot use `'` to surround tables and columns' names. The correct character is `\``. For strings, on the other hand, the correct one is `'`.

Comment: `mysql_` has been deprecated. Please use MySQLi or PDO instead. This is a post I've written on the topic, http://anuary.com/54/input-sanitization-and-escaping-for-database-and-stdout-using-php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to encapsulate tables within a query unless they have space or they are reserved words.

```
INSERT INTO 'lms'.'test2' ('trn') VALUES ('17')
// This makes no real sense to the db. It should be:
INSERT INTO lms.test2 (trn) VALUES ('17')
```

If the column trn accepts numbers, it really should be:

```
INSERT INTO lms.test2 (trn) VALUES (17)
```

With MySQL, you can use the *tilted quote* character to encapsulate names, but not strings. To enter a string in the query you will have to use normal quotes like `'`.

You can to this:

```
select `someTable`.`someColumn` from `someTable`
```

but not this:

```
select someTable.someColumn from someTable where myName=`Tommy`;
```

The correct use would be:

```
select someTable.someColumn from someTable where myName='Tommy';
```

Comment: added two backticks that you missed.

Comment: @ypercube Thanks mate, very very drunkies right now, so all backticks, single quotes and spaces are looking the same :)